# Solspace Calendar: List only recurring events

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I have a calendar for a location that combines recurring events with individual events. I'm trying to list out the upcoming events for the next 90 days, but I'm running into issues with the repeating events. I'd like to list the individual events by dates, and then have the repeating events listed once, with their rule (i.e. Every Monday: Event Title).

```
{% set eventOptions = {
    calendar: 'otherEvents',
    dateRangeStart: 'today',
    dateRangeEnd: '+90 days',
} %}
{% set otherEvents = craft.calendar.events(eventOptions) %}
```

This gives me a list of all events, but it is overwhelmed by recurring events. I can turn them off by adding loadOccurrences:false, but I'm having trouble loading them on their own.

```
 {% set eventOptions = {
    calendar: 'otherEvents',
    loadOccurrences: false,
} %}
{% set otherEvents = craft.calendar.events(eventOptions) %}
```

This gives me a list of individual events and a single instance of each repeating event, but it also shows expired events. As soon as I add a date range, the recurring events go away.

Is there any way to get JUST the recurring events, listed once, with their repeat rule? Essentially, i need a loadOnlyOccurrences option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation here is that the `loadOccurrences: false` parameter only checks for "Primary" events (first occurrence) within the specified timeframe. So if the first occurrence is outside of the specified timeframe, the event won't show at all.

Comment: So there is no way to limit the list to only recurring events? I could just leave the date range open-ended if there were a way to filter out then non-recurring events.

Comment: You're wanting to only list events that recur? As in, hide events that don't recur?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With only an individual instance of each recurring event. Ultimately, I want to have a list of all upcoming nonrecurring events in the next X days, with a list of all recurring events below it (also, is there a way to customize the output of the readableRepeatRule tag? It's way more verbose than I need).

Comment: This currently isn't possible with Calendar at this time. The only functionality available is to display all available recurrences OR the "parent" (first) occurrence only, as long as it fits within the timeframe. We do have what you're looking for on our feature request list however. :)

Comment: @Solspace Any update on this? I need to be able to list all active (having future occurrences) events in a list that has 'loadOccurrences: false', otherwise switching it off isn't that useful.

Comment: Sorry, this feature request has not yet been implemented.

Comment: @Solspace Any update on a timeline for this feature? If I have a lot of events that recur weekly then to create a list of the next up-coming set of occurrences is all but impossible as far as I can tell. The only sort-of-solution is to loop through with `loadOccurrences: true` and then exclude events that have already been output - which makes for a hard time paginating, not to mention is db query heavy on a medium or large size dataset.

Comment: It'll be ready in a couple weeks actually :)